# Ruby - pushing values from an array combination to a new array

Tags: ruby

I am trying to print all the different sums of all combinations in this array [1,2,3]. I want to first push every sum result to a new array b, then print them using b.uniq so that non of the sum results are repeated. 
However, with the code I have, the 3 repeats itself, and I think it is because of the way it is pushed into the array b.

Is there a better way of doing this?

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = []

b.push a

b.push a.combination(2).collect {|a,b| (a+b)}

b.push a.combination(3).collect {|a,b,c| (a+b+c)}

puts b.uniq
p b #[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [6]]
```

Can someone please help me with this? I am still new in ruby.

Comment: Do you need that array nesting in the result?

Comment: No I don't, I want to show them as separate values..

Comment: then you could just `p.flatten.uniq`

Comment: But the first `3` you see, it's not a result of a sum operation.

Answer (score 3):

Because an `Array` of arbitrary length can be summed using `inject(:+)`, we can create a more general solution by iterating over the range `1..n`, where `n` is the length of the `Array`.

```
(1..(a.size)).flat_map do |n|
  a.combination(n).map { |c| c.inject(&:+) }
end.uniq
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

By using `flat_map`, we can avoid getting the nested `Array` result, and can call `uniq` directly on it. Another option to ensure uniqueness would be to pass the result to a [Set](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html), for which Ruby guarantees uniqueness internally.

```
require "set"

sums = (1..(a.size)).flat_map do |n|
  a.combination(n).map { |c| c.inject(&:+) }
end

Set.new(sums)
#=> #<Set: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}>
```

This will work for an any `Array`, as long as all elements are `Fixnum`.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is an array of the possible sums, flatten the array before getting the unique values.

```
puts b.flatten.uniq
```

What is happening is uniq is running over a multi-dimensional array. This causes it to look for duplicate arrays in your array. You'll need the array to be flattened first.